# Passing all requests to /api/v1/** to the old api server

Tags: java, clojure, compojure, ring, clj-http

For the 2nd iteration of our API we are performing a complete re-write.

To make the transition smooth I would like to setup our new server with an API endpoint /api/v1/** such that it will become a mirror of the old server.

Is there any built in functionality in ring/compojure that will allow me to pass the entire request to clj-http (or other http client)?

---

*FIY: Both servers are written in Clojure using the Compojure and ring libraries.*

Comment: how about a proxy (nginx) infront which can do the routing based on the api version? just a thought.

Comment: I would rather avoid installing additional software on my server and use the features provided by the api. Though it is still an option that I'll consider.

Comment: @gagansingh Your suggestion helped me search for proxy implementation in clojure/ring which led me to my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on [ring-proxy](https://github.com/tailrecursion/ring-proxy), I used it exactly for the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.